# Is static friction considered to be a conservative force?

Tags: forces, work, friction, statics, conservative-field

The work done by static friction is 0.So shouldn't  it be a conservative force?

Comment: A force is not conservative because the work done by it is zero.

Comment: @Sam Well, the work done by a conservative force doesn't *have* to be zero, but if a force only could do zero work, then this work would be path independent and hence the force conservative. The real answer is that [the work done by static friction is **not** necessarily zero](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/530939/75633).

Answer (score 4):

Put a crate on a flatbed truck and have the truck drive in a circle while speeding up. The static frictional force that the flatbed exerts on the crate both keeps the crate moving in a circle *and* acts to speed the crate up along the direction of motion.  By the time the truck has completed one full circle (and so hence so has the crate), the crate has sped up to some larger speed $v$ than it started with.

That's the scenario.  Now, the work done by the static friction force is non-zero, because a component of it is always acting in the direction of motion of the crate.  However, the crate has taken a closed path (a circle, in this case).  This means that the frictional force cannot be a conservative force, because the net work done along a closed path for a conservative force is zero.

Finally, the misconception in the question is then apparent.  A static frictional force *can do work*, and in fact it can do it in a way that the work is non-zero along a closed path.

Comment: Excellent answer!